# When to use Where Clause and ON clause with Join mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following sql JOIN query:

```
public function exportAll($date) {
    $sql = "SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, u.lastname) as fullname, c.early_checkout_remarks, c.delayed_checkin_remarks, DATE(c.checkin_time) as checkin_date, DATE(c.checkout_time) as checkout_date, TIME(c.checkin_time) as checkin_time, TIME(c.checkout_time) as checkout_time 
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN checkin_checkout c 
    ON u.id=c.users_id 
    AND (DATE(c.checkin_time) = '%s' OR DATE(c.checkout_time) = '%s') 
    AND u.deleted IS NULL
    ORDER BY fullname,checkin_date";
    $records = $this->db->exec(sprintf($sql,$date,$date));
    return $records;
```

I only want records of users who are not deleted. But this query is also returning users with values in 'deleted' column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that I think you need to move

```
AND u.deleted IS NULL
```

into a `WHERE` clause. Currently that AND is applied to the join only, not to the final result. And since it's a LEFT join, it doesn't fully restrict the results.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(u.firstname, u.lastname) as fullname, 
  c.early_checkout_remarks, 
  c.delayed_checkin_remarks, 
  DATE(c.checkin_time) as checkin_date, 
  DATE(c.checkout_time) as checkout_date, 
  TIME(c.checkin_time) as checkin_time, 
  TIME(c.checkout_time) as checkout_time 
FROM 
  users u
  LEFT JOIN 
    checkin_checkout c 
      ON u.id = c.users_id 
      AND (DATE(c.checkin_time) = '%s' OR DATE(c.checkout_time) = '%s') 
WHERE 
  u.deleted IS NULL
ORDER BY 
  fullname,
  checkin_date
```

It's not clear from your question where the part about check-in dates should also be in the where clause. We'd need to know more about the requirements and your data structure. But it's something you can try if you need to.

Note also I reformatted your query - I (personally) find queries formatted like this can be read and understood a lot faster and more accurately. It's easier to see what is being done where, and what applies to what.

Comment: this works! but for knowledge, what is the difference between On clause and Where clause?

Comment: No problem. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped -
 thanks :-) As i mentioned in the question, the ON clause only applies conditions to the JOIN, specifically (i.e. it controls which rows will get included from the joined table), whereas WHERE applies conditions to the final output. You can learn more by taking a SQL tutorial with exercises and seeing for yourself what the results are. It will become much clearer and more intuitive when you try examples of it with some simple data.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query.

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, u.lastname) as fullname, c.early_checkout_remarks, c.delayed_checkin_remarks, DATE(c.checkin_time) as checkin_date, DATE(c.checkout_time) as checkout_date, TIME(c.checkin_time) as checkin_time, TIME(c.checkout_time) as checkout_time 
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN checkin_checkout c 
    ON u.id=c.users_id 
    Where (DATE(c.checkin_time) = '%s' OR DATE(c.checkout_time) = '%s') 
    AND u.deleted IS NULL
    ORDER BY fullname,checkin_date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(u.firstname, u.lastname) as fullname, c.early_checkout_remarks, c.delayed_checkin_remarks, DATE(c.checkin_time) as checkin_date, DATE(c.checkout_time) as checkout_date, TIME(c.checkin_time) as checkin_time, TIME(c.checkout_time) as checkout_time 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN checkin_checkout c ON u.id=c.users_id 
WHERE (DATE(c.checkin_time) = '%s' OR DATE(c.checkout_time) = '%s') 
AND u.deleted IS NULL
ORDER BY fullname,checkin_date";
$records = $this->db->exec(sprintf($sql,$date,$date));
return $records;
```

WHERE added after the JOIN. You can use with ON as well.